# Any downsides to using the ProfileProvider in ASP.NET

Tags: sqlprofileprovider

Are there any downsides like performance or gotchas in terms of functionality to using the built in ProfileProvider with .NET?

I will be storing office information, extra security questions, etc. Nothing to outrageous so it could be a good fit.

Answer (score 1):

It's not bad for novices, but I think it's tied to the whole membership and roles providers, which I have found to be needlessly cumbersome.

Comment: When you install the Sql Server schema for the membership and roles providers, the top level object is an application, and I guess the thinking is that you will have multiple "applications" running against the same database. I have implemented some providers from the interfaces, that was more what I found to be cumbersome.